# How to identify with services on FreeNode.net and navigate all IRC channels?

Tags: irc

I'm trying to access an IRC channel on FreeNode.

I can only access some IRC channels, but not to all of them. For instance, I can access `#wikipedia-en-help` channel, but when I try to access `#git` or `#github`  channels I get the following message:

> Cannot join channel (+r) - you need to be identified with services -
>   see https://freenode.net/kb/answer/registration

I'm on the [Freenode website](https://freenode.net/) but I don't really understand how to register or identify myself.

How can I identify with services to be able to use `+r` channels?

Comment: Have you read the webpage https://freenode.net/kb/answer/registration which has instructions? Any specific parts that you don't understand? As it is now, any answer I could post would be practically exact copy of that webpage.

Comment: @grawity "Register your IRC nick:
/msg NickServ REGISTER password youremail@example.com"
Where should I write the command above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said which IRC client you're using, so I'll be using [Freenode's Kiwi chat](https://webchat.freenode.net/) as an example.

Most IRC clients will have tabs for each channel you're in and each private messaging conversation you have with a user. They will also generally have a Status channel. This channel gives information about the server and your connection to said server.

To register with Freenode's services, you need to message NickServ, which is essentially a bot. The `/msg` command is used to start a private message conversation with a user or, in this case, a bot. The command can be entered into any tab associated with the network you're on.

If you're using the Kiwi chat, there is only one network: Freenode.

[image: Kiwi chat window]

You can write the command `/msg NickServ REGISTER password youremail@example.com` (where you replace `password` with your password and `youremail@example.com` with your email address) into any of the tabs you see in the image above.

This will create a new tab where the NickServ bot will respond to you. You can then issue commands to the bot without the `/msg NickServ` portion if you enter the commands into that specific private message tab.

[image: NickServ tab]

Once you're registered, you will need to `IDENTIFY` with NickServ every time you log in. You will do this by either using `/msg NickServ IDENTIFY password`:

> ```
> IDENTIFY identifies you with services so that you
> can perform general maintenance and commands that
> require you to be logged in.
>
> Syntax: IDENTIFY <password>
>
> You can also identify for another nick than you
> are currently using.
>
> Syntax: IDENTIFY <nick> <password>
>
> Example:
>     /msg NickServ IDENTIFY foo
>     /msg NickServ IDENTIFY jilles foo
> ```

Or you can enter your password on the login page:

[image]